# SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Login

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have created a new user in SQL server 2008 R2 Express but I am unable to login with it. I can login with windows authentication. I am getting following error:

### TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to .\MSSQLSERVER2.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Login failed for user 'asif37'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=18456&LinkId=20476

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Comment: Can you provide your connection string?

Comment: Have you set your SQL Server to allow both user/password and Windows Authentication? I believe it's configured to Win Auth only by default. There are a multitude of articles on the web regarding this.

Comment: To clarify, you can login with windows authentication, but not user/pwd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you enabled mix-mode authentication?  SQL Auth is disabled by default.

Here's the MSDN Page for configuring Auth modes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx